# How to add metadata to a folder on mac/linux

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, unix, mkdir

If I create a directory like so:

```
mkdir foo
```

or with node.js

```
fs.mkdirSync('foo');
```

is there a way I can add metadata to the folder to indicate that I created it (which user created it, or some other metadata). How would I read that metadata with bash or node.js?

Answer (score 5):

On linux you can add custom metadata to a file as [extended attributes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html), provided that you put them in the `user.*` namespace if you're not having the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability (~ if you're not root):

```
$ setfattr -n user.foobar -v quux file
$ getfattr -n user.foobar file
# file: file
user.foobar="quux"
```

I'm not using `node.js`, but you should look for `listxattr()`, `setxattr()`, `getxattr()`, `removexattr()` named shims -- those (and their `l*` and `f*` variants) are the system call interfaces to extended attributes.

Comment: Just to handle the other half (third?) of the question: on Mac, the same basic system exists using the `xattr` command rather than `setfattr`.

Comment: On MacOs you can also use [mdls](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/mdls/) to retreive metadata.

Answer (score 1):

No. The only user-related metadata is the owner of the directory (which will be your user when you create it, but can be changed via the `chown` command).

```
mkdir abc
ls -la
> drwxr-xr-x  2 jerric ORG\Domain Users   64 May  2 11:51 abc
```

`jerric` is the name of the user who created the directory.

Comment: yeah I think the call is `stat` to retrieve metadata, in node.js `fs.stat`